# Can spring container inject collaborators using custom methods?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Normally dependencies are injected via setters by the following configuration (http://static.springsource.org/sprin...beans-beanname) :

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean">
    <!-- setter injection using the nested <ref/> element -->
    <property name="beanOne"><ref bean="anotherExampleBean"/></property>

    <!-- setter injection using the neater 'ref' attribute -->
    <property name="beanTwo" ref="yetAnotherBean"/>
    <property name="integerProperty" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anotherExampleBean" class="examples.AnotherBean"/>
<bean id="yetAnotherBean" class="examples.YetAnotherBean"/>
```

Lets say the class `examples.ExampleBean` has a collection listeners objects, and the method `addListener(SomeListenerInterface)` is the only possible way add listeners. Can I inject listeners declaratively in xml like its done with property setters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably conjure up some baroque mechanism for doing this all in XML, but the cleanest way to do this is to use a `FactoryBean`. You write a class which implement `FactoryBean`, and which is responsible for constructing and configuring your target object (see [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)). Your `FactoryBean` would have the required getters/setters/autowiring, and injects them into the target object.

This is often the cleanest way to handle non-javabeans in Spring, particularly if you cannot modify the target class.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes property Element definition

> Property elements correspond to JavaBean **setter methods** exposed by the bean classes.

To get your goal, you can use @Autowired annotation. It works **even when using an arbitrary name**

```
@Autowired
public void inject(SomeListenerInterface someListenerInterface) {
    this.someListenerInterface = someListenerInterface;
}
```

Comment: That is possible but it would automatically inject all the 'SomeListenerInterface' beans in all beans that declare this attribute. Anyway, thanks for the info, I didnt knew about this attribute.